# ReactJS console.log disappearing after some second

Tags: reactjs, logging, single-sign-on

I am implementing SSO in my reactjs app on a button click and debugging one error by adding console.log to see the this.props.location variable. But as I click on the auth me button (that will trigger the sso auth) it shows the log for few second and then disappear. I have taken printscreen

[image]

I want to expand the object in console and view the attributes value , but unable to do it as it is disappearing. I have added wait timers also to hold the block but its getting hanged. Is there is a better way so that I can log the console.log's data to a file and view the errors peacefully without getting in a rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this code inside your submit button to prevent the default submit event.

```js
onSubmitClicked = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  //additional codes
}
```